# How to hide specific attribute in product edit form general tabs

Tags: magento-1.8, product, attributes, adminhtml

I need to hide a product attribute in the General tab while editing the product. How can I do it?

Comment: What exact fields would you like to hide?  Some of them are really required, like SKU.

Comment: I got Answer, I did it, I will update answer later. Thanks for asking:)

Comment: @Charlie Do you mind if I was why you want to do that?

Comment: @JulienLachal, I have multiple store magento application, where one store owner can't edit other store owners products, So I wanted to hide some attribute and tabs:0

Comment: @Charlie ok :) then would you mind putting your answer below and accept it so as other people wilkling to achieve the same find some help here? ty.

Comment: @JulienLachal, Sure, I am bit busy, I will update today Itself, hey Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above can be achieve by overriding following page

```
Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php
```

In that page you need to change  `_prepareLayout()` finction,

In that function all the product Tabs and attributes of each tabs are added to array, check below code

foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);
            // do not add groups without attributes

```
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
            if( !$attribute->getIsVisible() ) {
                unset($attributes[$key]);
            }
        }
```

In above code first foreach iterate the tabs [Attribute Groups] and second foreach iterates attributes of each tabs, and unset remove the attribute from array whose Visible is false, So while iterating you can set each attribute Visibility as false `$attribute->setIsVisible(false);` which you don't want to display in product edit/create form.

Its Simple and effective:)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where to use the code you paste ' $attribute->setIsVisible(false); ' ? I want to hide the 'Price' tab in the product edit page, was think of using some user restrictions before the addtab function but i cannot find it in Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php  , there is 'inventory' tab though.

> if(!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/catalog/any'))

Cheers
Jacek